# mysql unknown column in select query as

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Mysql returns unknown column "users.status" in "where clause"

```
    SELECT
    users.firstname,
    users.lastname,
    users.email,
    users.pref
   FROM (
    SELECT
        users.firstname,
        users.lastname,
        users.email,
        CONCAT(
            users.preference, ',',
        ) AS pref
    FROM users
) AS users

  WHERE  users.status = 1
  AND users.active = 1
```

Comment: If I am reading this right, you don't need a subquery here at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery doesn't include the `status` column.  Why not just write the query without the subquery?

```
SELECT u.firstname, u.lastname, u.email,
       CONCAT(u.preference, ',') AS pref
FROM users u
WHERE u.status = 1 AND u.active = 1;
```

You also have an extra comma at the end of the `CONCAT()` (which looks strange anyway, with just two arguments).